# Download a file from Azure Storage using Azure.Storage.Blobs .NET

Tags: .net, download, upload, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I'm using the NuGet package **Azure.Storage.Blobs v.12.14.1** to download a file from Azure Storage then upload the file to OneDrive.

Here is the code I am using:

```
var blobClient = new BlobClient({connection_string}, {container}, {file_path});
var blobSize = blobClient.GetProperties().Value.ContentLength;
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

long blockSize = (10 * 1024 * 1024);
blockSize = Math.Min(blobSize, blockSize);

long currentPointer = 0;
long bytesRemaining = blobSize;
do
{
    var bytesToFetch = Math.Min(blockSize, bytesRemaining);
    await using (var blobStream = await blobClient.OpenReadAsync(currentPointer, (int)bytesToFetch, null, cancellationToken))
    {
        blobStream.Position = 0;

        var fileContent = new StreamContent(blobStream);
        fileContent.Headers.ContentLength = bytesToFetch;
        fileContent.Headers.ContentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(currentPointer, currentPointer + bytesToFetch - 1, blobSize);

        var res = await client.PutAsync(fileConsentCardResponse.UploadInfo.UploadUrl, fileContent, cancellationToken);

        currentPointer += bytesToFetch;
        bytesRemaining -= bytesToFetch;
    }
}
while (bytesRemaining > 0);
```

When the file is less than the blockSize: 10MB, this is working fine. The file can be seen in the OneDrive after the code is executed.

However when the file is larger than the blockSize, this is no longer working. No error is thrown, but the file is not found in the OneDrive.

Help please, thanks!!

Update:

I made this working:

```
var blobClient = new BlobClient({connection_string}, {container}, {file_path});
var blobSize = blobClient.GetProperties().Value.ContentLength;
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

long blockSize = (10 * 1024 * 1024);
blockSize = Math.Min(blobSize, blockSize);

long currentPointer = 0;
long bytesRemaining = blobSize;
do
{
    var bytesToFetch = Math.Min(blockSize, bytesRemaining);
    HttpRange range = new HttpRange(currentPointer, bytesToFetch);

    var blobStreamResult = await blobClient.DownloadStreamingAsync(
        new BlobDownloadOptions { Range = range });

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        blobStreamResult.Value.Content.CopyTo(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var fileContent = new StreamContent(ms);

        fileContent.Headers.ContentLength = bytesToFetch;
        fileContent.Headers.ContentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(currentPointer, currentPointer + bytesToFetch - 1, blobSize);

        var res = await client.PutAsync(fileConsentCardResponse.UploadInfo.UploadUrl, fileContent, cancellationToken);
    }

    currentPointer += bytesToFetch;
    bytesRemaining -= bytesToFetch;
}
while (bytesRemaining > 0);
```

Having another issue, if the file is large (let's say 1GB), it will consume too much memories, how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the OpenRead Scenario:
I have a few questions on your code snippet because some of these methods are made by your namely:

```html
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
var res = await client.PutAsync(fileConsentCardResponse.UploadInfo.UploadUrl, fileContent, cancellationToken);
```

None of these APIs are owned by Azure.Storage.Blobs, can you provide the code snippet of this?
I’ve attempted a basic scenario where the buffer size was 10MB however I was unable to reproduce the your issue. So we would have to analyze , how exactly are you reading from the OpenRead Stream.

For the DownloadStreaming Scenario:
Looks like in might be buffering the entire stream twice (once when doing the CopyTo and when initializing the StreamContent). This sounds a little out of our bandwidth to be reviewing a code of a customer.

But I would recommend disposing the contents of the results from the DownloadStreaming after retrieving them, and to buffer part of the stream and pass it to the StreamContent, instead of trying to do everything all at once.